# Método del controlador devuelve a la vista algo que no debía

Tags: javascript, laravel

Edito:

En la parte superior de la pantalla, entre el body y los headers, me sale esto:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 14:10:16 GMT
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído que es por culpa de algún método del controlador que devuelve el cache-control en la response,pero esta vista la redirecciono desde el login directamente cuando el usuario se loguea. Pongo el código del controlador y vista:

Investigando, gracias a Javier Molla, hemos depurado todo el código, y he llegado a la conclusión, de que es este método el que me introduce esa cabecera, aunque no entiendo muy bien porque, ya que si utilizo un método parecido, pero sin pasarle datos en json, no me introduce la cabecera. EL caso es que he estado probando a cambiar el método para ver si puedo omitir el json, pero ponga como lo ponga me sigue devolviendo dicha cabecera, si a alguien se le ocurre algo, seria de gran ayuda

Método del controlador:

```
public function index()
    {
        $dataF = $this->obtenerDatos();
        //dd($dataF);
        return view('vacation.create')
               ->with('user_id',\Auth::user()->id)
               ->with('worker_name',\Auth::user()->name)
               ->with('data',$dataF);
    }
    public function obtenerDatos(){
       $data_fechas = [];
       $vacations =  $this->consultar('2');
       //dd($vacations);
       foreach ($vacations as $fechas){
         $datepickerData =  new \stdClass();
         $datepickerData -> area_id = $fechas->area_id;
         $datepickerData -> title = $fechas->observations;
         $datepickerData -> start = $fechas->date_from;
         $datepickerData -> end = $fechas->date_to;
         $datepickerData -> acept = $fechas->aceptado;
         $data_fechas[] = $datepickerData;
       }

    return $data_fechas;
}
```

Vista:

```
  @extends('layouts.app')
@push('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
      .day_red {
        background:#ffcccc !important;
      }
      .day_green {
        background: #ccffcc;
      }
      .day_orange{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffa300 0%, #ffffff 100%) !important;
      }
    </style>
@endpush
@section('content')
    <div class="app-content content container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div align="center" class="panel-heading"><h3>Registrar vacaciones a {{ ucwords($worker_name) }}</h3></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/vacation/store') }}" autocomplete="off">
                            {!! csrf_field() !!}
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('type') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tipo:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    {!! Form::select('type',['' => 'Seleccione un tipo...','vacacion' => 'Vacacion','falta' => 'Falta','permiso' => 'Permiso'],null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}

                                    @if ($errors->has('type'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('type') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('observations') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Observaciones:</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="observations" rows="5" id="observations"
                                              value="{{ old('observations') }}" required></textarea>
                                    @if ($errors->has('observations'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('observations') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user_id}}"/>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 mb-1">
                              <label >Fecha Solicitada:</label></div>
                              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('date_init') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Desde... Hasta...</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar3"></i></span>
                                        @if ($errors->has('date'))
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('date') }}</strong>
                                        @endif
                                        <input type="form" id= datefilter name="datefilter"/>
                                      <input type="hidden" name="area_id" id="inputarea_Id" class="form-control" value="{{old ('area_id')}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Vacacion</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             @include('errors.flash-message')
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('javascript')

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/ui/tether.min.js')}}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/core/app-menu.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/core/app.js')}}"></script>


                          <!--    DATE-PICKER   -->
<script>
  // here receive the json array from PHP to JS
  var daysData = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
  var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
  }
}

$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      var valid = false ; // default css class
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
         if(newA[d].acept == 1){
            valid =  true;
        }
      }
      return valid;
    },
   isCustomDate: function(date) {

      var daySettings = 'day_green';
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
       if(newA[d].acept == 0){
        daySettings = 'day_orange';
       }
      }
      return daySettings;
    },

    changeMonth: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    regional: 'es',
    locale:{
      "fromLabel": "Desde",
      "toLabel": "Hasta",
      "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
      "daysOfWeek": ["Lun","Mar","Mie","Jue","Vie","Sa","Dom"],
      "monthNames": ["Enero","Febrero", "Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"],
      applyLabel: 'Guardar',
      cancelLabel: 'Limpiar',
      monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
    }
});
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
});
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val('');
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Como se puede observar le mando el nombre del usuario y el id, con un array de datos en json para introducir dichas fechas en el datepicker.

Y añado una foto cuando inspecciono el elemento en el navegador, como se puede observar no existe tal linea de código en mi vista, y realmente en el método del controlador que le pasa todos los datos yo depurando no veo esa cabecera por ningún lado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con lo cual la pregunta seria, como puedo pasar los datos a la vista, sin que me meta la cabecera?.

Editado.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: La cabecera que muestra es en realidad la respuesta a la petición ¿El problema lo tienes cuando es tipoUsuario = 2? Deberíamos ver lo que haces en el método que se encarga de responder a /vacation/create por ver qué respuesta devuelve. Si es por la respuesta a /home, pues lo mismo

Comment: el metodo ese del login que puse, es el que redirecciona a la vista de vacation/create, y si, es solo con el usuario 2 y en esa vista, en todas las demas que tengo que solo tiene acceso el tipoUsuario 1 estan correctas. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Entonces la respuesta que obtienes es la que se devuelve en ese método

Comment: y como podria hacer para cambiar el metodo sin que devuelva esa respuesta? porque aunque hago dd no la veo por ningun lado para intentar omitirla

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres que devuelva? Pon el código de ese método y vemos qué está haciendo

Comment: Te edito la pregunta para ver si me puedo explicar mejor. Gracias por tus respuestas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82405/discussion-between-javier-molla-and-david-pazo-lopez).

Comment: Hola Javier, he depurado todo el código y reeditado el post para que quede mas claro el error, pero aun asi no he sido capaz de solucionarlo por ahora, seguire buscando la manera de mandarle los datos, saludos y gracias por todo, me has ayudado bastante.

Answer (score 1):

probando y probando encontré el error, tenia un middleware, que mandaba una response si el usuario era normal, con lo cual omití ese middleware, y automaticamente ya desaparecio.

Dejo el pedazo de codigo de las rutas y el middleware, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema o parecido pues que no se olvide de revisar bien todos los ficheros.

Rutas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'usuarioStandard'], function () {

    //Route::get('/', 'VacationController@index');
    //Route::get('/vacation/calendar', 'VacationController@index');
    Route::get('/vacation/create', 'VacationController@create');
    Route::get('/vacation/creat/{id_worker}/{name_worker}', 'VacationController@create');

});
```

Y el middleware:

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();
    if($usuario_actual->tipoUsuario!=2){
     return response(view("mensajes.msj_rechazado")->with("msj","Esta seccion es solo visible para el usuario estandard <br/> usted aun no ha sido asignado como usuario standard , consulte al administrador del sistema"));
    }
    return response($next($request));

}
```

Si.. un poco estupido por mi parte la verdad.

Gracias Javier por toda tu ayuda, sin ella no creo que lo consiguiera.

Saludos.

Comment: Enhorabuena, estas cosas cuestan de encontrar. Me alegro